# Angular form rendered with action attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, typescript

I am new to Angular 7 and I have an issue when a submitting a form. Whenever I submit the form it gets redirected to index.html (as per the action) instead of executing my typescript method.

This is the html for the component:

[image: HTML for the component]

and the component itself:

[image: Typescript for the component]

However this is how it gets rendered: (notice the actin=index.html attribute):

[image]

And when I click on the Login button it gets redirected as per the action:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: edit your component.ts screenshot : half of the content is hidden.

Comment: Try removing the `method="post"` from the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here seems to have been importing the ReactiveFormsModule not only in the component that I'm using but in the module that is loading the component as well. In my case the module was implemented using lazy loading. While the parent module did import ReactiveFormsModule the child module did not.

Importing the correct module in the correct place allowed the component to render correctly and the method is now executing perfectly.